# C : Segmentation fault with typecasting

Tags: c, network-programming, segmentation-fault, packet-sniffers, typecasting-operator

In my C code, my string ( of type 'char' ) contains the payload of a captured packet. Since some of its contents cannot be printed, I tried typecasting them to 'unsigned char'. I am getting a segmentation fault. 
Typecasting to 'char' results in the same.

Can typecasting result in segmentation fault? If yes, when does typecasting result in segmentation faults?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to check if the payload contains any URL. 
'payload_length' varies for each packet and can be pretty large.

```
char str[payload_length+10];
size_t size_read;
str[strlen(str)]='\0';//Adding '\0' after loading the payload contents.

if((pos=strstr((char)str,"http"))==NULL || (pos=strstr((char)str,"Host:"))==NULL || (pos=strstr((char)str,".com"))==NULL || (pos=strstr((char)str,"www."))==NULL)
printf("\nNo distinct URL is present\n ");

else
printf("\nURL is at %p ",pos);
```

Comment: It doesn't. Show your code.

Comment: Please don't talk about your code, there's a very big risk that you're missing something. Show the code, as minimal an example as possible.

Comment: *"when does typecasting result in segmentation faults?"* - When you use it to evoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Zero lines of shown code are too minimal and not at all complete or verifiable.

Comment: Do not use `char` to store data - doing so is dangerous, since char has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: is it made sure that `str` is NUL terminated?

Comment: @StoryTeller inside the expression of the 'if' condition.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yea.

Comment: regarding: `str[strlen(str)]='\0';`  this will not work correctly unless the array `str[]` is already NUL terminated.  Suggest using: `str[ payload_length+9 ] = '\0';

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: honor the page right hand margin.  In the current scenario, suggest starting a (indented) new line before each `||` operator.

Comment: `strstr((char)str,"http")` `strstr` does not expect a parameter of type `char`. Why do you cast your `char[]` to `char` when you need a string?

Comment: BTW: The majority of URLs worldwide might not contain a ".com" TLD and also lots of URLs don't start with "www.". If you want to find any URL you should rethink that approach.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
`(char)str`. You cast an array into a single `char`. This is nonsense and you should know why. Also, this should *not* compile cleanly without compiler messages, or your compiler is trash.

Problem 2: you update `pos` every time, and `||` has mandatory evaluation from left to right. It would be a very weird URL to have `"www"` after `".com"`. So after `pos=strstr((char)str,".com"` you point at the end of the string and you will never find `"www"` anywhere.

An alternative to writing such obscure one-liner code, could be something like this:

```
bool validate_url (const char* str)
{
  const char* MUST_CONTAIN[] =
  {
    "http",
    "Host:",
    ".com",
    "www"
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(MUST_CONTAIN)/sizeof(*MUST_CONTAIN); i++)
  {
    if(strstr(str, MUST_CONTAIN[i] == NULL)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Optimizations are possible if you can assume that the strings are present in a specific order (as you should be able to).

Problem 3: `strlen` assumes that the string is already null terminated, so you cannot write code like `str[strlen(str)]='\0';`.

Comment: I think 'Problem 2' is not quite correct as every `ststr()` gets `str` as first parameter and `pos` isn't used at all and "www" will be found before or after ".com" -- which is not quite clever but is the same in your `validate_url`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah yeah that's true. Anyway, most of the code in the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The order used in original code causes `pos` to point to the start of the URL if the condition is true. Otherwise it would point to ",com" which is probably rather useless.

Comment: I am using a gcc compiler on Linux and I'm just starting with network programming, I'm still learning. Thank you for all the negative votes. And, I couldn't post the entire code as it has more that 300 lines of code.